# Disabling access to wsdl file in Axis Service Listing (listing services from wsdl's)

Tags: java, xml, web-services

The listing of all deployed Services can be disabled by setting 'disableServiceList' to true in Axis; which is used in AxisServlet.java -> reportAvailableServices() .

However, is there a way to disable access to the wsdls ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few ways to do it. One of the way is to write a Filter for handling "wsdl"

http://www.coderanch.com/t/224470/Web-Services/java/Disable-wsdl-url-Axis#1054987